# Shorten or use Title as link on developer story exported resume - traditional view?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

When applying for a job a resume is attached.  I am not certain if it is the traditional view or some other view (as you guys have made the wording / terminology so confusing introducing the verbiage 'developer story').  In any event the readings section I really do think that the exported PDF should not include the entire URL for a book.  I think it would be much better if we just made the title of the book clickable.  Examples shown:

[image]

Comment: No freehand red circles?

Comment: I do agree... would need to make sure that its clear its a link still imo. (Also, in the mean time, you might consider removing the query params, [example](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Articulating-Design-Decisions-Communicate-Stakeholders-ebook/dp/B015X0WFCW/))